# "Attempts to access secure API” error in Blackberry - Phonegap

Tags: blackberry, cordova

When I tried to install my phonegap app in Blackberry device it's showing an error like "Attempts to access secure API".

But the same app running properly in "Blackberry Simulator".

How can I resolve this error?

Please help...

Comment: try to sign your app properly

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to sign your application before installing it on an actual device. Unsigned app works on simulator, but you need to sign it to run it on actual device.

Get your signing keys here: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html

**EDIT**: updated signing keys link, because RIM (BlackBerry) has updated their web-site and old link pointed to 404 error page.